# Audio volume lower, quality drops after ffmpeg amix multiple audio inputs

Tags: ffmpeg

I use ffmpeg to:

1. add multiple audio into a video file and offset them
2. discard original audio in the video

Everything is OK **except** that 
1. the audio volume in the `result.mp4` is remarkably lower than the volumes in each individual input audio
2. sound quality in `mp3`(which is a background music) also drops

I listened to each `3gp` and the `mp3` files, can confirm that the two issues above.

Why is this happening?

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 1.3gp -i 2.3gp -i 1.mp3
  -filter_complex "[2]adelay=10000|10000[s2];[3:a][1:a][s2]amix=3[a]"
  -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy result.mp4
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38714779/5726027

Comment: Thanks, I was also checking that thread. The command there works better, but still it does generate an optimal result. For example, at the begin of 5 secs, there is only one mp3 file as audio input, but the volume is still very low. From a noob point of view, why can't ffmpeg just stack these audios up then generate result?

Comment: I checked your explanation @Mulvya in that thread. In my case, there is always two active audio inputs at any given time, one is the mp3, the other one is a 3gp, i.e. none 3gp files overlaps.